# SpringBoot Define variables to use in the class

Tags: spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot project with two classes `DashboardController.java` and `DashboardService.java`. I need to define the variable that I get from the `Controller` to use it in the whole `Service` class. I explain the problem.

This is the method I have in the `DashboardController.java`, in which I collect by `URL` the variable `iniDate` from the front-end:

```java
@GetMapping(path = { "/{employee_id}/{iniDate}" })
public EmployeeDashboardDto getEmployeeDashboarYearInidDto(
    @ApiParam(value = "employee_id", required = true) @PathVariable("employee_id") Integer idEmployee,
    @ApiParam(value = "iniDate", required = true) @PathVariable("iniDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate iniDate
) throws QOException {
    return dashboardService.getEmployeeDashboardYearIniDto(idEmployee,iniDate);
}
```

And this is the method that I have in the `DashboardService.java` class in which I collect the `iniDate` variable from the `Controller`:

```java
public EmployeeDashboardDto getEmployeeDashboardYearIniDto(Integer idEmployee, EmployeeDashboardDto iniDate) {
    EmployeeDashboardDto initDate = iniDate;
    return initDate;
}
```

I'm not sure if I collect the variable correctly, but what I need first is to collect the variable from the front-end in the `controller` using the `URL`, then collect it in the `service` and finally define that variable is the `service` to use it in the rest of the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving the date in your controller and casting it as `LocalDate` then your method in the service class needs to receive the date in the same type `LocalDate`.

Change the parameter type to `LocalDate` like this:

```
public EmployeeDashboardDto getEmployeeDashboardYearIniDto(Integer idEmployee, LocalDate iniDate) {
    EmployeeDashboardDto employeeDashboardDto = new EmployeeDashboardDto();
    employeeDashboardDto.setIniDate(iniDate);
    return employeeDashboardDto;
}
```

If you need to receive dates as `PathVariables` you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55869770/5869384) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55857901/5869384) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following method in the `DashboardService.java` I have changed the name of the `initDate` variable:

```
public EmployeeDashboardDto getEmployeeDashboardYearIniDto(Integer employeeId, LocalDate iniDate) {
        EmployeeDashboardDto initDate = new EmployeeDashboardDto();
        initDate.setIniDate(iniDate);
        return initDate;
    }
```

And in the Dto I have created the following method:

```
public void setIniDate(LocalDate iniDate) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
```

But in the Service, in the methods that is used the `initDate` variable says that `initDate cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: Maybe it's better if you update your question with more details and the full classes you have mentioned

Comment: The only thing I have added is the method to set in the DashboardDto.java and in the DashboardService.java I have added the method you said but changing the name of the variable to initDate, but in the rest of the ways I can't read that variable